# How to apply security updates to python3 on MacOs

Tags: python, macos

I am running python V3.6.8 on Mojave and the most current version of that branch is 3.6.10, however I can't find any information on how to upgrade from 3.6.8 to 3.6.10.

On python.org there are no dmg files for either 3.6.9 or 3.6.10, so how do I upgrade to 3.6.10 to pickup the latest security patches.

There is a reason why I don't want to move out of that branch, otherwise I would just download the latest release.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment for your project?

Comment: I am not. I use Linux to develop and I use the Mac to test it there to make sure it also works there, just like I do in windows, so I need to keep the Mac and Windows installs on the same branch as Linux, but I can't figure out how to upgrade to 3.6.10

Comment: @jrpy _so I need to keep the Mac and Windows installs on the same branch as Linux_ Virtual environments should help with that, too.